# How to do Log System on Django?

Tags: python, django

I researched a lot of topics and i read some blogs. But i can't best way to do log system. I want to do log system that it can record users actions such as delete,update and create. Especially, this system should be record before and after changes like django admin in history.

For example;

[image: hi]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use **django-simple-history** module as it stores the history on every create/delete/update action on field. I am personally using the it for all my backup history. It is really helpful.

Please find the link https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ to have more clearance on the same.

Comment: Especially, this system should be record before and after changes like django admin in history. So, in this package is it possible?

Comment: Yes, on every update on a particular file, it provides you an update log which you can later modify according to your need.